# How do I print char[] in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, printing, char

When I try to print my char array I just get a bunch of boxes [][][].

Here is my code. How do I print this and get the number value array such as [1,2,3]?

```
package Com;

import java.util.*;

public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Solution l1 = new Solution();

//        int[] x = {3,3,7,7,10,10,11};

        String[] x = {"eat", "tea", "tan", "ate", "nat", "bat"};

        l1.groupAnagrams(x);
    };

    public List<List<String>> groupAnagrams(String[] strs) {
        List<List<String>> ans = new ArrayList<>();
        Map<Integer,List<String>> m = new HashMap<>();

        for(String s: strs) {
            char[] chars = new char[26];
            for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
                chars[c-'a']++;
            }
            System.out.println(chars);
        }

            return ans;
        };
    };
```

Comment: Why are you storing ints in a char array?

Comment: It looks like `char[] chars` is supposed to contain the counts of characters. Surely those counts are integers, not characters?

Comment: @shmosel To convert it into a hashcode and then compare two objects such as eat and tea

Comment: Huh? What hashcode?

Comment: So is your real question "How can I produce a hashcode that is the same for strings with the same letters in a different order, but different for strings with different letters"?

Comment: @Jason I know how to do that part but I was just wondering if I could print this as it is

Comment: Then John Kugelman has answered your question, and it has nothing to do with hashcodes.

Comment: @Jason He just gave me another way to do it.  I was wondering if theres a way to do it with type char.

Answer (score 3):

You should be creating arrays of `int` not `char`. The array holds character *counts*, not characters. For clarity let's rename it to `counts`.

```
int[] counts = new int[26];
for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
    counts[c-'a']++;
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(counts));
```

Then to get a readable string call [`Arrays.toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString-int:A-).